# Stringify macro with runtime values

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

I'd like to print a macro with a runtime value inside. Is this possible and if so how?

```
#include<iostream>
#define DOSOMETHING(value) 5 * value + 6;

#define STRINGIFY(macro, arg1) std::cout << macro( << arg1<< );

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    STRINGIFY(DOSOMETHING, argc)
    return 0;
}
```

This should print "5 * (value of argc) + 6" so if argc is 0 then it prints "5 * 0 + 6"

How can this be done?

Code sought after macro expansion:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::cout << "5 * " << argc << " + 6";
    return 0;
}
```

The point is to allow the creating of a c++ code generator without having all the code to be generated in strings which disables syntax highlighting and makes it very difficult to test.

Comment: You don't define RETURN anywhere, and you don't use DOSOMETHING anywhere.  Also, did you mean the value of `STRINGIFY` to be `std::cout << macro( <<arg1<<)`.?

Comment: What's wrong with `#define OUT(var) std::cout << "5 * " << (var) << " + 6";`

Comment: Clearly, you don't *actually* want to print out the value of argc - this is just a sample problem.  However, it isn't clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MartinBonner I fixed the macro names, I have a runtime code generator and lots of c++ code in strings makes it hard to comprehend what will be generated and testing it. With macros I'd at least be able to write tests and get some syntax highlighting

Comment: @john - If you modify it a bit to `#define OUT(var) "5 * " << (var) << " + 6"` then it's usable in `#define STRINGIFY(macro, arg1) std::cout << macro(arg1);` to give the exact output the OP wants. You should post an answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller ... but it doesn't solve the OP's problem.  He has a runtime code-generator, and DOSOMETHING, err, does something - but he wants to be able to debug it.

Comment: @MartinBonner no I clarified in response to your question

Comment: @MartinBonner - Eh, you mean the OP wants to analyze arbitrary expressions and stringify parts of them? I suppose I missed that on an initial read. Yeah, that's a no-starter with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want with the syntax you want (the preprocessor just doesn't have the necessary introspection capabilities).

I think you are more likely to have success with some sort of expression template system, where you can write something like:

```
auto doSomething = Magic(5) * Magic::arg + 6;
```

then one can write:

```
doSomething.generate(arg);
```

or

```
doSomething.print(arg)
```

WARNING:  I am pretty sure the exact syntax above won't work - but it's a starting place to look.  (I would suggest looking at Boost.Proto, but there may well be other suitable libraries.)